# Find whether kernel thread associated with a user thread is blocking or not

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Consider a many-to-one mapping from User threads to Kernel threads. How do I find out whether the kernel thread associated with a particular user thread is blocking or non-blocking?

Comment: I don't think you can do this portably using just pthreads/POSIX interfaces. You'll have to be more specific about which platforms you're targeting and why you want to know this.

Comment: I am just curious about it. Not using it in practice.